# Determine the colours used by the ASP.NET Chart control

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-charts, color-palette

I'd like to find out which colours are used for a particular pallette in the ASP.NET Chart control.

I already know there is an enum on the Chart class to set the palette, e.g.

```
myChart.Palette = ChartColorPalette.Berry;
```

But I'd like to know which colours belong to the palette.

Before anyone asks - as I know you will - the reason I need to know the colours is because I want to create my own legend outside of the chart image.

I also know that I can set my own colours on the DataPoints for the chart, but I'd rather not have to implement my own palette.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [Setting Microsoft Chart Series Colors](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexgor/archive/2009/10/06/setting-chart-series-colors.aspx) and [Colors in ASP.NET](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Colors/default.aspx)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I used the ApplyPaletteColors() method to apply the colours to the chart and then iterated over the data points to get their Color properties.